# Ionic3 country not selected on edit profile

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I have country select box on edit profile page, where I want to make select country default which is save by user. But it's not get selected.

```
 //TS file countries.

   this.country = [
   {id:"AX", name: "Åland Islands"},
   {id:"AF", name: "Afghanistan"},
   {id:"AL", name: "Albania"},
  {id:"DZ", name: "Algeria"}
 ]
```

And the selected country of uer is defined in variable array like.

```
userData = {"country": localStorage.getItem('country')};
```

Now in view I am displaying it like.

```
  <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Country </ion-label>
     <ion-select (ionChange)="setStateValues(userData.country)" [(ngModel)]="userData.country" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          <ion-option [value]="countryVal" *ngFor = "let countryVal of country" [selected]="countryVal == userData.country">{{countryVal.name}}  </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

But the country does not get selected in view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop, an example of countryVal is `{id:"AX", name: "Åland Islands"}`
so you need to reference the ID of the countryVal, so you can compare with the ID saved for the User.

Also for best practices, use `===` for string comparison.

Change your option do this

```
<ion-option [value]="countryVal" *ngFor = "let countryVal of country" [selected]="countryVal.id === userData.country">{{countryVal.name}}  </ion-option>
```